# Try to join more than one table

Tags: mysql, database, join, view

[Tables And what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wlfn.png)
I'm trying to Create a view  with 5 tables for a school project. The statement so far goes like this:

```
CREATE view lager AS 
Select produkt.produktNumber,
(SELECT buyphone.lagerNummer FROM bluecity.buyphone) AS 'Lagernummer',
produkt.produktBrand,
produkt.produktModel,
sizeMemory.memoryInformation,
(SELECT buyphone.colorValue FROM bluecity.buyphone) AS 'Farve',
(SELECT buyphone.conditionValue FROM bluecity.buyphone) AS 'Stand'
FROM bluecity.produkt
JOIN bluecity.sizememory ON bluecity.produkt.memorySize = bluecity.sizememory.memorySize
JOIN bluecity.color ON buyphone.colorValue = bluecity.color.colorInformation
JOIN bluecity.conditions ON buyphone.conditionValue = bluecity.conditions.conditionInformation
```

But i can't seem to get the joins right. The main table bluecity.produkt needs to join some of it's values with other table. The first join with Memory size works, but that is it. The main table is supposed to hold an Integer Value which draws meaning from the joined table if that makes sense.

Help is much appriciated, if you can explain why and how it would be even better so i can try to understand.

Added create stmt

```
CREATE DATABASE bluecity;


CREATE TABLE bluecity.Member 
(memberNumber INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
zipNumber INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
phoneNumber INTEGER(8) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
statusValue INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (zipNumber) REFERENCES bluecity.zipCode(zipNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (statusValue) REFERENCES bluecity.ID(statusValue),
PRIMARY KEY (memberNumber));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.ID 
(statusValue INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
information VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (statusValue))



CREATE TABLE bluecity.zipCode 
(zipNumber INTEGER(4) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (zipNumber));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.Produkt 
(produktNumber INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
produktType VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
produktBrand VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
produktModel VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
memorySize INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (memorySize) REFERENCES bluecity.sizeMemory(memorySize),
PRIMARY KEY (produktNumber));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.Conditions 
(conditionValue INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
conditionInformation VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (conditionValue));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.sizeMemory 
(memorySize INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
 memoryInformation VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (memorySize));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.Color 
(colorValue INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
colorInformation VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (colorValue));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.Prices 
(conditionValue INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
produktNumber INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
price INTEGER(6) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (conditionValue) REFERENCES bluecity.Conditions(conditionValue),
FOREIGN KEY (produktNumber) REFERENCES bluecity.Produkt(produktNumber),
PRIMARY KEY (conditionValue, produktNumber));

CREATE TABLE bluecity.buyPhone 
(IMEI Integer(15) NOT NULL,
lagerNummer INTEGER(7) NOT NULL,
produktNumber INTEGER(5) NOT NULL,
colorValue INTEGER(2) NOT NULL,
conditionValue INTEGER(1) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (produktNumber) REFERENCES bluecity.Produkt(produktNumber),
FOREIGN KEY (colorValue) REFERENCES bluecity.Color(colorValue),
FOREIGN KEY (conditionValue) REFERENCES bluecity.Conditions(conditionValue), PRIMARY KEY (IMEI));
```

Comment: How many recordxs do the subqueries (the one in braces) return?

Comment: Well i think it only returns one.

Comment: Are you working with multiple databases? Otherwise, why kepp mentioning the database name. Also, your question is unclear. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I've added create statement and a illustration of the tables and what i'm looking to acheive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Select DISTINCT produkt.produktNumber AS 'Produkt #',
        buyphone.lagerNummer AS 'Lager #',
        produkt.produktBrand AS 'Mærke',
        produkt.produktModel AS 'Model',
        sizeMemory.memoryInformation 'Hukommelse',
        color.colorInformation AS 'Farve',
        conditions.conditionInformation AS 'Stand',
        prices.price AS 'Pris'
        FROM bluecity.buyphone
        JOIN bluecity.produkt ON bluecity.buyphone.produktNumber = bluecity.produkt.produktNumber
        JOIN bluecity.sizememory ON bluecity.produkt.memorySize = bluecity.sizememory.memorySize
        JOIN bluecity.color ON bluecity.buyphone.colorValue = bluecity.color.colorValue
        JOIN bluecity.conditions ON bluecity.buyphone.conditionValue = bluecity.conditions.conditionValue
        JOIN bluecity.prices ON bluecity.produkt.produktNumber = bluecity.prices.produktNumber
        JOIN bluecity.prices p1 ON bluecity.buyphone.conditionValue = bluecity.prices.conditionValue
```

I got it working like this, thx guys.
Edit: there still was some flaws which i think is fixed now.

Comment: This doses not make sense JOIN bluecity.buyphone ON bluecity.buyphone.lagerNummer = bluecity.buyphone.lagerNummer JOIN bluecity.buyphone u2 ON bluecity.buyphone.colorValue = bluecity.buyphone.colorValue JOIN bluecity.buyphone u3 ON bluecity.buyphone.conditionValue = bluecity.buyphone.conditionValue You are not joining on the foreign key
Try adding more entries to buyphone table and it wont work

Comment: You were right, and i found out that i needed to use the table buyphone as a main table. Everything works as it should like this, though the might be something  wrong with it still.

Answer (score 0):

You should also make a join on the bluecity.buyphone instead of having it as subqueries in your select, as it is related to your produkt table.
Something like this:

```
Select produkt.produktNumber,
buyphone.lagerNummer AS 'Lagernummer',
produkt.produktBrand,
produkt.produktModel,
sizeMemory.memoryInformation,
buyphone.colorValue AS 'Farve',
buyphone.conditionValue AS 'Stand'
FROM produkt
JOIN buyphone ON buyphone.produktNumber = produkt.produktNumber 
JOIN sizememory ON produkt.memorySize = sizememory.memorySize
JOIN color ON buyphone.colorValue = color.colorInformation
JOIN conditions ON buyphone.conditionValue = conditions.conditionInformation
```

Comment: I've tried this, but i can't get it to join proberly, i'm not sure what i should join it on though?

Comment: Close to what i needed, though you gave me the tools to get through it Thanks alot.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do then?